# RegEx count words excluding html tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've got the following scenario.

I have a page where we have a tinymce editor where we can paste text. There is an option to limit the characters or words to be pasted in the editor.

I have a text like this

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br />quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br />consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br />cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br />proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br />quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br />consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br />cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br />proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br />quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br />consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br />cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br />proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br />quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br />consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br />cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br />proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br />quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br />consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br />cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br />proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br />quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br />consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br />cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br />proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>
```

Which according to SublimeText is 342 words long.

If I remove the html tags, Sublime says it's 368 words long and MS Word it's 379.

I'm trying to find a RegEx that finds all words excluding the html tags, to have a proper word count on our system.

So far I've tried

```
/[\w\u2019\'-]+/gim
```

But that includes the characters inside the HTML tags, as seen here

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mC1hE1/2)

I've also tried with

```
(\s+|>)\w+
```

Which is getting closer, but that also includes the > sign that are part of html entities, as seen here

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mC1hE1/1)

Bare in mind that I can't do a replace of the text within angle brackets, because this text editor is used for scientific and medical paper submissions, so in some cases those symbols < and > are used for notations.

Comment: Can't you extract only the text with `textContent` or `innerText`,and count that ?

Comment: The famous 'Don't use regex on HTML, because HTML is not a regular language' post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: if the html is not recursively nested, and especially if it doesn't have weirdo attribs or invalid HTML, then RegExp is fine. in fact, if the input does have unescaped `<`s, then a DOM-based solution will likely "crap out"

Comment: Have you tried what Gaby suggested?

Answer (score 1):

A plugin for TinyMCE actually exists which [counts the word of a given text](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/wordcount/).

Here's a slightly adapted version of [tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/wordcount/](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/tree/ddfa0366fc700334f67b2c57f8c6e290abf0b222/js/tinymce/plugins/wordcount)
 which should fit your purpose.

```js
         toPlainText = function(string) {
      var tx = string;
      var tc = 0;
    
      if (tx) {
       tx = tx.replace(/\.\.\./g, ' '); // convert ellipses to spaces
       tx = tx.replace(/<.[^<>]*?>/g, ' ').replace(/&nbsp;|&#160;/gi, ' '); // remove html tags and space chars
    
       // deal with html entities
       tx = tx.replace(/(\w+)(&#?[a-z0-9]+;)+(\w+)/i, "$1$3").replace(/&.+?;/g, ' ');
       tx = tx.replace( /[0-9.(),;:!?%#$?\x27\x22_+=\\\/\-]*/g, ''); // remove numbers and punctuation
    
       var wordArray = tx.match(/[\w\u2019\x27\-\u00C0-\u1FFF]+/g);
       if (wordArray) {
        tc = wordArray.join(" ");
       }
    
}
     var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = tc;
      return div.textContent;
    }    
    
    document.write(toPlainText("<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br />quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br />consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br />cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br />"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify it by breaking it down to:

```
var text = "<p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p sdf>Lorem ipsum</p>";

var words = text.replace(/(<([^\s>]+)>)/ig, " ").trim().split(/\s+/).length;

console.log(words); // output: 6
```

- first remove all the html tags using `replace` with a regex
- use `trim`
- then `split` all the words using a regex (so that whitespaces don't count as words)

and finally you have the number of words.

**Please notice** that I have used the following regex to replace `/(<([^\s>]+)>)/ig`:

- Tags like `<p>`, `</p>`, etc. are replaced whereas
- Tags like  (including a whitespace) are **not** replaced.

This should give you a good approximation.

Comment: As OP said, _Bare in mind that I can't do a replace of the text within angle brackets, because this text editor is used for scientific and medical paper submissions, so in some cases those symbols < and > are used for notations._

Comment: @noob Good catch! I've updated my answer a bit. What do you think of it?

Comment: I won't try tinkering with replace as OP strictly mentioned that **_in some cases those symbols < and > are used for notations_**. 

Anyways what do you think of my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

### **To count the words.**

I improved upon your regex to check for `<>/` characters around the word.

**Regex:** `/[^<>/]([\w\u2019\'-]+)(?!\s*\/>)/gmi`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mC1hE1/3)

Comment: Definitely looks interesting! It works great with tags that consist of one character. Longer tags increase the word count. Another idea is to create a regex that really only removes/excludes html tags - that would maybe be most accurate?

Comment: @sjkm: **Definitely**. But is that the requirement of this question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="test">
    <p>foofoofoofoofoo</p>
    <h1>googoogoogoogoogoo</h1>
```

```
<script>
    var allText;
    var divElm = document.getElementById('test');
    for (text in divElm.childNodes) {
        allText += divElm.childNodes[text].textContent;
    }
    alert(allText);
</script>
```